# Pod is not visible after sometime

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, deployment, namespaces, kubernetes-pod

I deployed a pod in Kubernetes cluster. The deployment is success and I am able to see my pod running. But after sometime my pod is missing from the list of workloads.Why is this so?

Comment: Can you provide more detailed information of your setup?  Did you see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#voluntary-and-involuntary-disruptions ?

Comment: Also did you use kubectl command to list, get and describe pod - are they visible from console using kubectl command?

Comment: Yes.I used kubectl. The pod is not visible.Is it because of my restartPolicy in my deployment file? I configured restartPolicy as On Failure.So after the deployment is running and moves to Success stage , is pod destroyed(Lifecycle of pod)?

Comment: Can you provide more detailed information of your setup - config files (deployment), environment specification and also logs.